# $f$ which is differentiable at $a$, but it is not differentiable at some point in any neighborhood of $a$. ("Dialogues on Calculus" by Kohji Kasahara)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, analytic-functions

I am reading "Dialogues on Calculus" (in Japanese) by Kohji Kasahara.

Hotta is one of the fictional characters in this dialogues.
Hotta says as follows:

> If $f$ is analytic at $a$, it is analytic at any point in a neighborhood of $a$.
> This is unbelievable.
> If $f$ is continuous at $a$, it it possible $f$ is not continous at some point in any neighborhood of $a$ in general.
> If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, it it possible $f$ is not differentiable at some point in any neighborhood of $a$ in general.

I found $f$ which is continuous at $a$, but it is not continuous at some point in any neighborhood of $a$:

> Let $f$ be a function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$.

I was not able to find $f$ which is differentiable at $a$, but it is not differentiable at some point in any neighborhood of $a$.
Please tell me an example.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^2$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and otherwise $0$.

Comment: $x^2$ if $x$ is rational and 0 otherwise

Comment: @Riemann Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: (A) No need to have Special Case $f(0)=0$ because that is covered by $f(x)=x$ over rationals. (B) When trying to get Differentiable function using a Continuous function , you can try "integrating" that Eg $x$ will suggest $x^2$ over rationals.

Comment: @Prem Thank you very much for your comment, especially for (B).

Comment: It is possibile to make $f(x)$ continuous. Namely there is a continuous nowhere differentiable function $g(x)$ [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Then $f(x)=x^2g(x)$ is differentiable at $0,$ and nowhere else

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much for your elegant answer.